# What does double colon mean in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm completely new to Rust programming language. While studying [this lesson](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html), I kind of didn't understand the following two lines.

```
let mut guess = String::new();
```

and,

```
io::stdin()
```

What is the use of double colon in both cases?

Comment: Relevant: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html?highlight=colon#paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree

Comment: @E_net4 the curator I mentioned that, I'm a newbie. So, it's a bit complex for me. Thanks BTW.

Comment: That is fine. I am only stating that continuing to read the book would eventually get you to the relevant section.

Answer (score 5):

`::` behaves like a namespace accessor. You can navigate through modules or specify locations like `std::io::stdin()` or call methods for objects like in `String::new()`. It can even be mixed, since an object may be in a module itself, so for example, the full path to the String new method would be `std::string::String::new`.

Refer to [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html?highlight=colon#paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree) for more information.

Comment: String::new() is like calling object methods in JavaScript, right? // I have JavaScript background

Comment: @AbirSheikh, not really, it is just the full path to the funtion itself. In this case it would be like a static method, since the object it is not constructed still. You can think of it like a method under a object namespace.

Comment: Its kind of like calling a method from a library; sort of like if you did console.Log() in JS or in Python if you did time.time()

Answer (score 2):

The symbol :: can mean various things based on where and how it is used. Please refer [Table B-3: Path-Related Syntax here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html). However most common use case where most of us will use it is as Namespace path.
Example:

```
use std::io;
```

Here we are trying to use io module from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

`::` name is a double colon am I correct
according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols_by_introduction_date

`::` called [proportion sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportion_sign)

but I prefer a double colon.

You can use it to import modules and carate in rust.

```
use std::collections::HashMap // add this to anywhere before using HashMap
fn main() {
    let solar_distance = HashMap::from([
        ("Mercury", 0.4),
        ("Venus", 0.7),
        ("Earth", 1.0),
        ("Mars", 1.5),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's *mathematical* symbols. How does that relate to Rust here aside from the code listed?

Comment: Its General Knowledge. You must know